# htc desire z cannot receive exchange emails completely

Tags: email, htc-desire-z, exchange

My **HTC Desire Z** has the latest **Android 2.2.1** system, and my company's exchanges is the latest **Exchange 2010**. After I set up the Exchange Sync, I am **able** to receive email. People in my company loves to send long emails, and Android is so smart that it did not download the email at once, but allowing me to download the remaining part of the email as I scroll down. And there comes the problem...no matter how hard I scroll down, it just cannot get the missing part.

Comment: Can you be a little clearer about the issue you're trying to resolve? (There's a reason no one has responded to your question for a month-and-a-half.) Is it that your e-mail client is not downloading complete messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attender from HTC asked me to remove my exchange account and add it again, and the problem is solved.

Comment: I'm glad you got your issue resolved. Please remember to "accept" this as the solution so it can act as a signpost to future visitors who have the same issue.